# Feature detection from satellite images

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-processing

I'm having a couple of thousand clear satellite pictures and would like to extract features out of them, like *outdoor swimming pools*, *solar panels*, *presence of green space*, ... I was wondering if there is one particular way or algorithm to obtain that kind of information?

Answer (score 1):

Swimming pools in satellite images have been studied in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.471.1233&rep=rep1&type=pdf.
It involves crowdsourcing and active learning of a SVM classifier in a sliding window approach. The same approach could also be used for solar panels and green space.